# Find the range of $a$ from given equation

Tags: functions

I want to find the range of $\alpha$ with $A, B, C$, $p_1$ and $p_2$.

$Ax + B y +Cxy \leq 0$.

$(1-\alpha)p_1 \leq x \leq (1+\alpha)p_1$.

$(1-\alpha)p_2 \leq y \leq (1+\alpha)p_2$.

How can I solve these equations to find a range of $\alpha$?

Comment: What are $\;A,B,C, p_1,p_2\;$ ? Is there any relation between them?

Comment: No, there is no relation between them. they are independent. I want to find range of $\alpha$ w.r.t. variables $A,B,C,p_1,p_2$.

Comment: Do you mean $Ax+By+Cxy\le 0$?